# Moving big data that has to be encrypted

Tags: transfer

I'm just a software developer here, but my boss wanted me to do some research on this topic.  Basically we need to move terabytes of data from one geographic location to another(pretend we are moving locations.)  This data HAS to be encrypted once it leaves our building.  What is the industry standard or best practice for handling such a transfer?  Is there a proper encryption protocol that should be used for data of this size?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Use HTTPS with certificate pinning.

Comment: I think they're wanting to physically move the data though.  Our network probably isn't fast enough.